# How to count numbers of categories in a table with / without Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let say we have a table with data about books stored in bookcases by topic:

```
N       Shelf1    Shelf2   Shelf3
Case1   Python    PHP      Python
Case2   Rails     R        PHP
Case3   PHP       Python   Python
```

So I need to count how many books by each topic we have in our library like this:

```
Python: 4 books
PHP: 3
R: 1
Rails: 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first reshape your dataframe to a 'stacked' record, and then use `value_counts` function.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ===================
print(df)

Out[269]: 
       N  Shelf1  Shelf2  Shelf3
0  Case1  Python     PHP  Python
1  Case2   Rails       R     PHP
2  Case3     PHP  Python  Python

# processing
# ======================================
# make column 'N' as index, stack, then value_counts
df.set_index('N').stack().value_counts()

Out[270]: 
Python    4
PHP       3
Rails     1
R         1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ravel` on the `values` attribute which returns a np array to flatten your df and from this construct a Series and call `value_counts`:

```
In [42]:
pd.Series(df[['Shelf1','Shelf2','Shelf3']].values.ravel()).value_counts()

Out[42]:
Python    4
PHP       3
Rails     1
R         1
dtype: int64
```